# UICollectionView's didSelectItemAtIndexPath method is called only once

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have `UIView A`. `UIView A` is loaded with `UICollectionView`. That is fine. In this situation, whenever I touch `UICollectionView's cells`, `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` is called.

Sometimes, there is a condition I need to load `UIView B` loaded onto `UIView A`. `UIView B` is loaded and once its process is completed `UIView B` is setHidden.

The problem is `UIView B` is loaded and setHidden, after that when I touch `UICollectionView's cells`, `didSelectItemAtIndexPath is not called`.

What is wrong with this problem?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried to remove View B from View A after the process is complete?

Comment: Post some code to get idea !

Comment: @channi yeah that may be good idea. Let me test.

Comment: @batuman Have you use any Gesture recognizer in view B?

Comment: @Jaimish yes the problem is because of UITapGestureRecognizer. I need that because UIView B has UITexField and to remove the KeyBoard I need UITapGestureRecognizer. Once UITapGestureRecognizer is loaded onto the UIView A, UICollectionView's TapGesture doesn't work.

Comment: @batuman So when you hide viewB then remove TapGesture from view B, and when you again show viewB then add TapGesture again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the UITapGestureRecognizer of View B when you hide that view and then When you show View B, again add UITapGestureRecognizer in View B.

It will work definitely.

When you hide view B.

```
[ViewB removeGestureRecognizer:YourTapGesture];
```

When you show view B.

```
[ViewB addGestureRecognizer:YourTapGesture];
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try this after your UIViewB loaded and setHidden

```
[viewA bringSubviewToFront:collectionView];
```

Guess this will work.

Answer (score 1):

yes @Jaimish's suggestion is correct. I have UITapGestureRecognizer inside UIView B. Once UIView B is loaded, UICollectionView's TapGesture doesn't work.